# Count matches in an array

Tags: c++, debugging, matching

I can't figure out how to do this.

The question: Implement the function

```
int count_matches(const string arr[], int size, string query);
```

Return the number of strings in the array that are equal to `query` or
`-1` if size if less than 0.

My answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int count_matches(const string arr[], int size, string query){

  int i = 0;
  int numMatches;

  for (;i<size;i++) {

    if (string[i] == (string[i]+1)){
      numMatches++;
    }

  }

  return numMatches;

}


int main(){

  string selection;

  const string array[4]={"dog", "cat", "dog", "dog"};

  cout<<"which animal do you want?"<<endl;
  cin>> selection;

  cout<< "there are " << count_matches(array, 4, selection)<< " matches"<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your array name is `arr`, so what is `string[i]`? Also, look at `string[i]+1` and think about what its doing, also since `int numMatches;` is uninitialized, what do you think `numMatches++;` will do? And where do you use `query`?

Comment: You don't use the `query` variable at all.  I don't that's probably what you intended...  Oh and you probably should initialize `numMatches`...

Comment: how do i "reinitialize" numMatches?

Answer (score 1):

```
int count_matches(const string arr[], int size, string query){

  int numMatches(0);

  for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
  {
    if (arr[i] == string)
    {
      ++numMatches;
    }
  }

  return numMatches;
}
```

This should be a solution to your problem but you will never learn anything from gaining the answer this way. I'd advise reading this [tutorial on arrays and loops](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/63-arrays-and-loops/) to better understand how to tackle the problem next time.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your code to compile, you need to look carefully at this block:

```
if (string[i] == (string[i]+1)) {
    numMatches++;
}
```

What do you actually want to compare here? `string` is a *type*. Take another look at the arguments that you pass into the function and that should make it clear.

Then, once you have a match, you increment `numMatches`. But what value does this have to start with? What value *should* it have to start with?

---

Note that [**`std::count()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) does exactly what your `count_matches()` function should do:

```
std::count(array, array + 4, selection)
```

This will probably not statisfy whomever marks your homework, but it is worth playing with and learning if you want to advance your C++ skills.

---

Good luck!